# What is minimal path in graph after Dijkstra's Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

My result graph after appling algorithm is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiO7U.png)

What does vector P mean in this grapth? `Р = {1, 1, 5, 5, 1}.` Also what is short path from vertex 1 to 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector P indicates the parent for each node in the graph, that is, the previous state in the optimal path from the start to the node.

- Node 1 is the start state and has 1 (itself) as its parent.
- Node 2 is reached optimally from 1, so 1 is the parent of 2.
- Node 3 is reached through the path 1-5-3, so 5 is the parent of 3.
- Node 4 is reached through the path 1-5-4, so 5 is the parent of 4.
- Node 5 is reached optimally from 1, so 1 is the parent of 5.

Following the parents, 4 is reached from 5 and 5 is reached from 1.

Comment: Do you mean Node is Vertex?

Comment: Yes, a node is another name for a vertex.